# apply dependently typed constructor in hypothesis

Tags: coq

Consider the following inductive definition:

```
Inductive T (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
  | c1 : T n n.
```

This works:

```
Theorem a : T 1 1.
Proof.
  apply c1.
Qed.
```

But this doesn't:

```
Theorem b : T 1 1 -> True.
Proof.
   intros H.
   apply c1 in H.
```

Both calls to `apply` seem equivalent to me, but the latter fails with `Error: Statement without assumptions`. Why? And how can I make it work?

Comment: `H` has type `T 1 1`. `c1` takes an implicit natural number. What should `c1 H`'s type be?

Comment: I see... on second thought, `apply c1 in H` doesn't really make sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question arose from my poor understanding of the `apply` tactic. @gallais's comment made me realize why `apply c1 in H` doesn't really make sense. The tactic essentially works as a function application on `H` and `c1 H` doesn't really make sense. For future reference, this is an example in which `apply in` would make sense. If we had another constructor `c2` like this:

```
Inductive T (n : nat) : nat -> Prop :=
  | c1 : T n n
  | c2 : forall x, T n x -> T n (S x).
```

Then `apply c2 in H` would transform something of type `T n x` into something of type `T n (S x)`, for example:

```
Theorem b : T 1 1 -> True.
Proof.
  intros H.
  apply c2 in H.
```

transforms the hypothesis `H : T 1 1` into `H : T 1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between proving `H` or proving `H -> True`. The Coq standard library already defined a proof of `True`, called I.
Hence:

```
Theorem b : T 1 1 -> True.
Proof.
  intros; apply I.
Qed.
```

But please also note that:

```
Theorem prove_I : forall p : Prop, p -> True.
Proof.
  intros; apply I.
Qed.
```

And as a consequence `H -> True` does not prove `H`, there's no correlation between the inhabitants of the two type.

Answer (score 0):

The `apply` tactic works differently when it is applied to a goal or a hypothesis. Applying `H : A -> B` has the following semantics:

- if the goal was `B`, then it will be transformed to `A` after `apply H.`
- if the hypothesis `H1 : A`, then it will be transformed to `H1 : B` after `apply H in H1`

This makes the reasoning correct; so it does not introduce inconsistencies.